# Meteor: How to get uncompressed files for debugging client side

Tags: meteor

How can I get uncompressed JS for debugging client side with Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running meteor locally in development mode, the javascript should already be uncompressed (i.e. not minified).

If you want uncompressed javascript after deploying, use the `meteor deploy --debug` command

(See http://docs.meteor.com/#meteordeploy)